# React.js - Setting a state item as an Array item, referencing in other state items then updating state when Array Item changes

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, methods

Heres my question, if I update a state item which has been set to an Array item (array[0]) to another item in that Array (array[1]) and I've got other state items that are referencing that array, should react know that the other state items need to be updated?

If yes then why does my test below not work:

```
Class Decking extends React.Component  {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { 
            firstOption: props.product.acf.options.product_option[0],
            title: props.product.title,
        }

        this.state.product = {
            mainImage: {
                url: this.state.firstOption.image_gallery[0].source_url,
                alt: this.state.firstOption.image_gallery[0].alt_text,
            },
            thumbnails: this.state.firstOption.image_gallery,
            price: this.state.firstOption.price,
            dimensions: this.state.firstOption.dimensions,
            options: props.product.acf.options.product_option,
            desc: this.state.firstOption.description,
            spec: this.state.firstOption.size___length_spec
        }
    }

    toggleOptions(id) {
        const option = this.state.product.options[id]
        this.setState({firstOption: option})
    }

    render() {
        return (
           <div>
                <div className="flex flex-wrap">
                    <div className="w-1/2">
                        <img className="w-full shadow-xl" alt={this.state.product.mainImage.alt} src={this.state.product.mainImage.url} />
                        <div className="-ml-2">
                        {this.state.product.thumbnails.map((thumbnail, index) => (
                            <img className="w-16 border-solid border-3 border-blue-400 mx-2" key={index} src={thumbnail.source_url} alt={thumbnail.alt_text} />
                        ))}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="w-1/2 pl-8">
                        <h1 className="text-4xl leading-normal">{this.state.title}</h1>
                        <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-between text-2xl mb-6">
                            <div className="font-light">
                            {this.state.product.dimensions}
                            </div>
                            <div className="font-light">
                            <b>Price:</b> {this.state.product.price}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <span className="text-xl font-light mb-4 block">Avaliable Options:</span>
                        <div className="flex flex-wrap mb-6 lg:mb-0">
                            {this.state.product.options.map((option, i) => (
                            <div className="w-full border-solid border-1 border-blue-400 shadow-lg flex items-center mb-4 px-5 py-4" key={i}>
                                <input onChange={e=>this.toggleOptions(e.target.id)} id={i} type="radio" /> <p className="checkChange mb-0 pl-4">{option.profileoption}</p>
                            </div>
                          ))}
                        </div>
                        <div className="w-full nomargin mb-4">
                            <b className="text-xl">Desc:</b>
                            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.product.desc}} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="w-full nomargin">
                            <b className="text-xl">Spec:</b>
                            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.product.spec}} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>

        )
    }
}
```

I've set `this.state.firstOption` to an array item `props.product.acf.options.product_option[0]`

That item changes when my `toggleOptions` method gets called :

```
toggleOptions(id) {
    const option = this.state.product.options[id]
    this.setState({firstOption: option})
}
```

And here is where the the method is called:

```
<div>
    {this.state.product.options.map((option, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
            <input onChange={e=>this.toggleOptions(e.target.id)} id={i} type="radio" /> <p>{option.profileoption}</p>
        </div>
     ))}
</div>
```

I hope I've made my question clear, I appreciate your attention :)

Comment: I can confirm that `this.state.firstOption` is getting changed but the states that it is being referenced from do not change at any point. So I guess react is creating new items for these instead of JS typical behaviour of referencing the original Array item

Answer (score 0):

Within `toggleOptions` `this` will be undefined. To solve this you can bind the event handler in the constructor like this:

```
constructor( props ){
    super( props );
    this.toggleOptions = this.toggleOptions.bind(this);
  }
```

Or you could define `toggleOptions` as an arrow function like so:

```
const toggleOptions = (id) => {
    const option = this.state.product.options[id];
    this.setState({firstOption: option});
}
```

Using an arrow function automatically binds the scope of `this` to the function.

Comment: this is not undefined in this case.. I've tested this because if I change the title inside the method (``` title: option.profileoption ```) it does change the DOM to the correct title.. I've tested and confirmed before that it is getting the correct item from the array!

Comment: I've console logged the option to double check and can confirm it is getting the correct array item, so it looks like it is being set but just not rendering the other state items